# Convert Unixtime to Datetime SQL (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, unix-timestamp

I have a datetime field(P_DT) and I would like to return all results where P_DT is greater then an input unix timestamp.

Does Oracle have any built in functions that can help?

In my searchs I find resuts for DateTime to Unix but no Unix to DateTime...

Comment: `numtodsinterval('.$_GET["date"].',\'SECOND\')`... You're vulnerable to SQL injections with this: use parametrised queries instead on passing the values directly by string concatenation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are no built-in functions.  But it's relatively easy to write one.  Since a Unix timestamp is the number of seconds since January 1, 1970

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION unix_ts_to_date( p_unix_ts IN NUMBER )
  RETURN DATE
IS
  l_date DATE;
BEGIN
  l_date := date '1970-01-01' + p_unix_ts/60/60/24;
  RETURN l_date;
END;
```

which you can see being called

```
SQL> select unix_ts_to_date( 1336822620 ) from dual;

UNIX_TS_TO_DATE(133
-------------------
2012-05-12 11:37:00
```

Comment: I ended up using

to_date(\'1970-01-01\',\'YYYY-MM-DD\') + numtodsinterval('.$_GET["date"].',\'SECOND\')

Where date is a code in the url of the unix timestamp.

But your solution is much more "official"

Comment: Unix timestamp is the number of seconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 **UTC**. Unless the database server runs on UTC you should use `(TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' + numtodsinterval(p_unix_ts,'second')) AT LOCAL`

Answer (score 0):

I used this in the end...

```
date=unixtimestamp number

to_date(\'1970-01-01\',\'YYYY-MM-DD\') + numtodsinterval('.$_GET["date"].',\'SECOND\')
```