# convert oracle varchar date read into variable to linux date

Tags: sql, bash

I am reading dates `'VARCHAR(14)'` from an oracle table with a sql query in BASH, into a variable.  I want to compare that date (eg. `20140611120520`) with the system date.  If the variable date is 15 minutes or older than the system date I need to kick off another procedure.
This is my query:

```
Get_einlag_time=`sqlplus ips_osmr/ips_osmr << eof | awk ' $1 == "This" { print $2 } '
select 'This ' || DZ_EINLAG
from LAG_SPI
where C_STATUS like '%E%' ;
eof
`
```

`$Get_einlag_time` - may result in more than one date seperated by a space  (eg. `20140411141231 20140605075650`)

I then read the dates one by one fom this variable with a `For GET_TIME in $Get_einlag_time` loop, comparing them with the system date.

Now I have this date value in `$GET_TIME` but I cannot do a date comparison as I get 'invalid date' from this variable.

This was my latest try in convertion before I gave up to ask for expert advice :-)

```
echo "time read from Get_einlag_time is $GET_TIME"
EINLAG_TIME=$(date +%Y%m%d -d "$GET_TIME")
EINLAG_CHK=$(date -d "$EINLAG_TIME+15 Minutes" +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
EINLAG_SEC=$(date -d "$EINLAG_TIME" +%s)
COMPARE_TIME=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
COMP_SEC=$(date +%s)
```

The `$EINLAG_SEC` converted %s gives me an extremely huge and unlikely value.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you'd do it like this:

```
SELECT CAST ('This ' AS TIMESTAMP) || DZ_EINLAG AS This
from LAG_SPI
where C_STATUS like '%E%' ;
```

Not sure if the syntax works but you get the idea.

If it doesn't work you might as well refer to here for getting unix timestamps properly:

[Convert timestamp datatype into unix timestamp Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105691/convert-timestamp-datatype-into-unix-timestamp-oracle)

Actual probable solution:

```
GET_TIME=${R:0:4}/${R:4:2}/${R:6:2}\ ${R:8:2}:${R:10:2}:${R:12:2}  ## Where R is like 20140411141231
```

Comment: I get what your're suggesting and will play around with it thx. <br> The 'this' and Print$2 is used in my awk to get rid of the headers etc when the oracle query returns so have clean data.

Comment: and for the link you gave.  It can only work when I have the date value from oracle converted into a date format recognized by unix.  I still have this problem that i'm reading a string VARCHAR from oracle and have to convert that into a date

Comment: You may try converting `20140411141231` to `2014/04/11 14:12:31` like: `R=20140411141231; D=${R:0:4}/${R:4:2}/${R:6:2}\ ${R:8:2}:${R:10:2}:${R:12:2}`. And use `"$D"` for the date. I should have examined those first sorry. I quickly assumed that it's having a different timestamp format.