# how to get time in millisecond from date field of oracle for the date 01-01-9999

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I want to get milliseconds from date field of oracle for date "01-01-9999".

I have created below block to achieve the same.

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
    base_point constant timestamp := to_timestamp_tz('01-JAN-1970 00:00:00.000+00:00', 'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS.FFTZH:TZM') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
    now timestamp := to_timestamp_tz('01-01-2099 00:00:00.000+00:00', 'DD-MM-RR HH24:MI:SS.FFTZH:TZM') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
    -- now constant timestamp := systimestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' ;
    n number;
begin

  select to_timestamp_tz(to_char(todate,'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')||'.000+00:00','DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS.FFTZH:TZM')
  into now
   from t_table where ACCOUNTID = 'ACC001124211';

 DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(' now :'||now);

 n := (
                  ((extract(day    from (now-base_point)))*86400)
                + ((extract(hour   from (now-base_point)))*3600)
                + ((extract(minute from (now-base_point)))*60)
                + ((extract(second from (now-base_point))))
           ) * 1000;

           DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(' n :'||n);
end;
/
```

but using above block I am getting value as `4070908800000`, which is equal to date  `1/1/2099` but actual date in my table is `01-01-9999`

Can you please help us to get exact millisecond using date field

Comment: This is the same thing as [Convert timestamp datatype into unix timestamp Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105691/convert-timestamp-datatype-into-unix-timestamp-oracle)

Answer (score 6):

No need of **PL/SQL**, you could do it in plain **SQL**.

To **convert a date to milliseconds** since `01-JAN-1970`:

```
SQL> SELECT to_number(DATE '9999-01-01'
  2         - to_date('01-JAN-1970','DD-MON-YYYY')) * (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) milliseconds
  3  FROM dual;

      MILLISECONDS
------------------
   253370764800000

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you are getting wrong value is this statement.

```
select to_timestamp_tz(to_char(todate,'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')||'.000+00:00','DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS.FFTZH:TZM')
```

Since your format element for year is YY, to_char conversion will have only 2 digits for year.

```
select to_char(date'9999-01-01','DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')||'.000+00:00'    char_date
from dual

char_date
------------
01-01-99 00:00:00.000+00:00
```

When you convert this to timestamp using YY as format element, the year returned always has the same first 2 digits as the current year, which is why you get 2099 as year.

```
select to_char(to_timestamp_tz(to_char(date'9999-01-01','DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')||'.000+00:00','DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS.FFTZH:TZM'),'yyyy') char_date
from dual;

char_date
------------
2099
```

**Moral of the story:**

Oracle recommends that you use the 4-digit year element (YYYY) instead of the shorter year elements for these reasons:

- The 4-digit year element eliminates ambiguity.
- The shorter year elements may affect query optimization because the year is not known at query compile time and can only be determined at run time.

Answer (score 1):

I've posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63597872/6866545) some methods to convert timestamp to nanoseconds and nanoseconds to timestamp. These methods are not affected by time zones and have a nanosecond precision.

You just need to adjust it to get milliseconds instead of nanoseconds.
You need to convert date to timestamp using "CAST(DATE_HERE AS TIMESTAMP)".

```
SELECT (EXTRACT(DAY FROM (
    CAST(SYSDATE AS TIMESTAMP) --Replace line with desired timestamp --Maximum value: TIMESTAMP '3871-04-29 10:39:59.999999999 UTC'
- TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC') * 24 * 60) * 60 + EXTRACT(SECOND FROM
    CAST(SYSDATE AS TIMESTAMP) --Replace line with desired timestamp
)) *  1000 AS MILLIS FROM DUAL;

MILLIS
1598447857000
```

Answer (score 0):

I got my solution both ways::

millis to date
`select to_date('1970-01-01 00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24') + (1424217600000)/1000/60/60/24 from dual;`

date to millis (similar to date.getTime() in java)
`SELECT to_number(to_date('18-02-2015 00','dd-mm-yyyy hh24') - to_date('01-JAN-1970','DD-MON-YYYY')) * (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) milliseconds FROM dual;`