# ORA 00933 sql command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle

I wrote this block of code

```
SELECT max(order)
FROM orders_table
GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) DIV 30 ;
```

Order is a column that I'm trying to take the max of every 30 seconds from a table called orders_table. I found the last line of code on here in the answer to someone elses program. However, I get an error when I try to run this code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no function `unix_timestamp()` in Oracle.

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105691/convert-timestamp-datatype-into-unix-timestamp-oracle

Answer (score 0):

Your query uses MySQL syntax. In Oracle server, neither `DIV` nor `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` exists.

To do integer division, you may just `TRUNC` the results of the division.

To compute the number of seconds since January 1st, 1970, you could use the following expression (since Oracle, when substracting dates, returns the result as a number of days) :

```
(date_column - TO_DATE('1970-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')) * 60 *60 *24
```

You probably want :

```
SELECT MAX(o.order)
FROM orders_table o
GROUP BY TRUNC(o.timestamp - TO_DATE('1970-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')) / 30 )
```