# Timestamp to number

Tags: oracle, unix-timestamp

How to convert the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP function in a NUMBER using ORACLE?

Using the following code, I'm able to extract the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP of the system

```
SELECT SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) FROM DUAL;
```

What I want is to use the result of the above code to create the corresponding timestamp in unix format.
Pratically:
1) with SELECT SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) FROM DUAL;
   i receive this result:

```
--------------------------------------------------
|    SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)          |
--------------------------------------------------
|       30-OTT-14 09:51:43,164232000             |
--------------------------------------------------
```

2) And I want to convert it to:

```
--------------------------------------------------
|               UNIXTIMESTAMP                    |
--------------------------------------------------
|                 1414662703                     |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Is that possible?
Thank you all in advance

Comment: Did you saw this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105691/convert-timestamp-datatype-into-unix-timestamp-oracle

Answer (score 5):

if you need to work with timestamps than you may try this

```
select trunc(
         extract(day from intvl) * 24 * 60 * 60 
       + extract(hour from intvl) * 60 * 60 
       + extract(minute from intvl) * 60
       + extract(second from intvl)
       )
from
(select SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - to_timestamp('19700101', 'YYYYMMDD') intvl from dual);
```

The difference between two timestamps is an interval

EXTRACT(fmt FROM INTERVAL) extracts date time component from an INTERVAL

TRUNC truncates milliseconds

Comment: From his example, where the `unixtimestamp` value has no decimal places, he apparently does not need to work with the precision of timestamps. That aside, your solution is, of course, correct and nice.

Comment: @nop77svk Yes it's true. It's enough to used dates, but not the current_date because this date is in session's timezone. As I understand the OP needs UTC time.

Comment: @nop77svk CAST(SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as DATE) instead of current_date would be more precise

Comment: Absolutely correct. Thank you for noting, now I finally understand what exactly the `sys_extract_utc()` function does. :-)

Comment: No need to maintain two answers anymore, yours alone covers the question nicely.

Comment: @nop77svk Thanks, but I think both our answers are just dublicates ))

Comment: Yup, they are (duplicates to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554405/convert-unixtime-to-datetime-sql-oracle ), but one has to gain the reputation points somehow. ;-)