# Convert number to date

Tags: sql, oracle, date, select

In Oracle, I have column named Create_date with data returning as 1400003659, 1400072380, and 1403796514 as examples. The column type is NOT NULL NUMBER(15). I'm trying to edit my SELECT statement to return these values as dates (or are these dates and times?).

**I've tried the below, but all are returning errors**:

```
SELECT to_date(Create_date, 'YYMMDD'),

SELECT to_date(to_char(Create_date), 'YYMMDD'),

SELECT to_timestamp(Create_date, 'YYMMDD'),

SELECT to_date(LPAD(Create_date, 15, '0'), 'YYMMDD'),

SELECT to_date(LPAD(Create_date), 'YYMMDD'),
```

**An example error message I'm receiving:**

```
SQL Error: ORA-01843: not a valid month
01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"
```

Comment: They look like UNIX Timestamps - this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554405/convert-unixtime-to-datetime-sql-oracle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a unix timestamp which is the number of seconds since 1/1/1970.

If you want just the date, you need to calculate the number of days and add it to 1/1/1970 like so:

```
to_date('1970-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') + numtodsinterval(1400003659,'SECOND')
```

If you want to retain the timestamp, you can do so like this:

```
to_char(to_date('1970-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') + numtodsinterval(1400003659,'SECOND'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

[See this for more information.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16461/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-a-datetime-in-a-view)

Comment: Thanks! Replacing the test value of 1400003659 with the column name Create_date works great!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
select to_date('01-01-1970 1:00:00','MM-DD-YYYY HH24:Mi:SS') + (1400003659/86400) from dual;
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/15214)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to know what that number means.

If those are UNIX dates (number of second since January 1, 1970), then you can use simple date arithmetic from that baseline by adding the value / 86400 (seconds in a day) to jan 1 1970:

```
select to_date('01011970','ddmmyyyy') + (1400003659/86400) from dual;

returns: 13/05/2014 5:54:19 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers are not precise! UNIX time is seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 **UTC!**

So, unless your database server runs on UTC you should do it like this:

```
SELECT
   (TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' 
        + 1400003659 * INTERVAL '1' SECOND) AT LOCAL
FROM dual;
```

or

```
SELECT
   (TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' 
         + numtodsinterval(1400003659,'second')) AT LOCAL
FROM dual;
```

or to get the time at time zone of database server's operating system

```
SELECT
   (TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' 
         + numtodsinterval(1400003659,'second')) AT TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'tzr')
FROM dual;
```